# An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x3) was found in the element content of the document in selenium

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testlink

During execution of test cases through selenium(Java) we are unable to update the status(Passed/failed) in the Testlink .The below error has been encountered after execution.

[Fatal Error] :802:33: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x3) was found in the element content of the document.

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to remove the invalid XML character.

`0x03` (aka `^C` aka `ETX` aka *end of transmission*) is ***[not an allowed character in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)*** :

> ```
> [2] Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```

Your data is not XML as long as it contains this character, and any conformant XML processor must report this error.

You must repair the data by removing any illegal characters by treating it as ***text, not XML,*** manually or automatically before using it with any XML libraries.

Comment: Note that control characters show up in some text editors (e.g. 0x03 shows up as `^C` in Textmate.  You might try copy/pasting over your questionable text to find funky characters visually!  Or, regex can always track these characters down, too.